# How to incorporate future observations in Keras custom loss function?

Tags: python, keras, loss-function, loss

I would like to implement a very specific custom loss function for a time series problem that depends on future observations of `y_true`. Something like this:

```
import keras.backend as K

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.maximum(0.0, y_true - y_pred) + K.maximum(0.0, y_pred - sum(y_true[j] for j in range(T))
```

`T` is a fixed parameter. So the loss in the current period depends on the observation in the current period + all observations in the `T` following periods. Obviously it's not possible to index `y_true` like this, but how can I incorporate future observations in the loss function?

Comment: why do you think it's not possible? your labels are a vector of size T+1, which should also be the size of your last layer

Comment: I don't think so. The labels (`y_true`) are a tensor where the first dimension is the batch size. What if T > batch size?

Comment: The tensor is of size [batch_size,T+1], if the current period is the first element of your labels vector, you can access it at y_true[:,0], and the rest of the periods at y_true[:,1:]

Comment: Ok, thanks! But the current period is only the first element of the labels vector in period 1. I would need something like y_true[:,i] for the current period and y_true[:,i:] for the rest of the periods. How do I access the current period i?

Comment: If you use time series, you have to use sets with shapes (samples, timesteps, features), you are confusing the batch dimension (samples) with timesteps, which are not the same.